# Php. urlencode function

Tags: php, url

I am using `urlencode()` function to prepare URL with Cyrilic symbols.
As a result I got:

```
%3Cstring+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2F2003%2F10%2FSerialization%2F%22%3E%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%3C%2Fstring%3E
```

How can I remove all unnecessary info like `%3Cstring+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2`?

Comment: Can you provide some code? What did you pass to `urlencode()`?

Comment: Result from bing tranlator
https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get this XML stuff inside your encoded URL it was there before. You need to fix your input.

Comment: My input is a result from bing translator. `var_dump()` displays only needed string, but `urlencode()` outputs something weird